# My team member not supporting to use Crystal report in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, crystal-reports

My team member not supporting to use Crystal report in asp.net web application. specially Crystal report with mysql database. Is there any other report available?

Comment: If they don't support it, they should suggest alternatives that overcome their objections to it.

Comment: no man specially CR with mysql only .thay are not supporting...even we are no able to use CR easily like sqlserver,It need connector to connect MYsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataDynamics' active report](http://www.datadynamics.com/) If you wan't to link it to a MySql database you'll need a ADO.NET data provider for MySQL

Comment: Data provider are like connector or what??

Comment: Yes,  http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ you're probably allready using it if you are working with ASP.Net and a mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

We've used DevExpress [xtrareports](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/) - they have asp.net, winforms, silverlight, and wpf versions. I found them a lot more customisable than Crystal Reports.